# DisplayLinkManager High CPU usage

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, displayport

I am currently experiencing high CPU usage when ever I'm using my Thinkpad USB 3.0 ultra dock that has a screen connected with DisplayPort. I also have another screen connected with a HDMI cable directly into my Thinkpad T480s but this shows no lag. I know there has been some questions about this earlier but they seemed to have no solutions, so I was hoping something new had happened. Does anybody have any tips? I'm thinking of just connecting the screen with HDMI to the dock to avoid Displayport and then the lag? I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I can provide more information if necessary.

Best Regards

Comment: Is it lag or high CPU usage?

Comment: Using htop it stays above 70% CPU usage.

Comment: Same thing, 30% to 70%, crazy.